# Read and temporarily hold XML content from a file in Groovy

Tags: xml, rest, groovy, xml-parsing, soapui

I'm trying to parse an xml file which has multiple contacts with the help of Groovy. What I want to do is get each contact from this file in xml and send it as part of a REST request, one by one. I tried writing a groovy script with the help of XmlParser as well as XmlSlurper, but haven't been very successful in doing so. I'm very new to Groovy.

Here are the contents of the file:

```
<contacts>
    <contact>
        <firstName>Dummy</firstName>
        <lastName>Contact1</lastName>
        <gender>M</gender>
    </contact>

    <contact>
        <firstName>Dummy</firstName>
        <lastName>Contact2</lastName>
        <gender>F</gender>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

Here is my attempt at the code using XmlSlurper:

```
import groovy.xml.*

//get the file path
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def projectPath = groovyUtils.projectPath
def f = new File(projectPath + '\\contacts - xml.txt')

//check if file exists
if(!f.exists())
{
    throw Exception("The XML File does not exist")  
}

//parse file
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(f)
log.info xml
```

The following is the output I get for the above code:

```
DummyContact1MDummyContact2F
```

I can also access invidual nodes by, for example:

```
log.info xml.contact[0].gender
```

Also when I use XmlParser, instead of XmlSlurper, I get a response which seems even more unusable:

```
contacts[attributes={}; value=[contact[attributes={}; value=[firstName[attributes={}; value=[Dummy]], lastName[attributes={}; value=[Contact1]], gender[attributes={}; value=[M]]]], contact[attributes={}; value=[firstName[attributes={}; value=[Dummy]], lastName[attributes={}; value=[Contact2]], gender[attributes={}; value=[F]]]]]]
```

Is there a way I can read the content from the file as xml and store it in a variable that holds xml, so that I can simply pass this into a REST Post Request? There's no way of knowing the number of contact records that will be in the file or the number of nodes per contact.

Comment: Are you using SoapUI-Pro? The -Pro does this sort of thing out of the box.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Using the free version.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with `XmlSlurper()`. Just continue your script:

```
def contacts = xml.'**'.findAll { it.name().equals('contact') }
contacts.each {
    // do something with the contact
    log.info it.firstName.text()
    log.info it.lastName.text()
    log.info it.gender.text()
}
```

Have a read through the [documentation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html).

You could rewrite each contact into the appropriate Request - you did not specify what you want that to look like. Store that in a variable:

```
testCase.setPropertyValue('myContact', myContact)
```

And then in your Request you could unwrap it with `${testCase#myContact}`.

Even the free version of SoapUI has [built-in loops](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/controlling-flow.html), so you could just loop over all that as many times as you need: until `${testCase#myContact}` becomes empty.